# There is a work on codepen it maked with threejs and we want to change its color

Tags: javascript, css, three.js, 3d, blob

We find a blob experiment on Codepen (https://codepen.io/vcomics/pen/ZwNgvX). And we want to use it but there is a trouble. It's color changing on this perlin object (rcolor, gcolor, bcolor);

```
perlin: {
    speed: 0.4,
    size: 0.7,
    perlins: 1.0,
    decay: 1.20,
    displace: 1.00,
    complex: 0.50,
    waves: 3.7,
    eqcolor: 0,
    rcolor: 1, <--
    gcolor: 0, <--
    bcolor: 0, <--
    fragment: false,
    points: false,
    redhell: true,
  }
```

It seems like RGB code but its not. We write red's rgb code (255, 255, 0) but it doesn't work. There is a example about this on three.js's website;

```
//Separate RGB values between 0 and 1
var color = new THREE.Color( 1, 0, 0 );
```

(https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/math/Color.set)

Edit:

There is a controller added on expirement page after we asked this question. You can easily control color of blob from there.

Comment: `eqcolor: 0.0,
rcolor: 1.0,
gcolor: 0.0,
bcolor: 0.0,
redhell: false`

These settings will give you pure red.

Answer (score 0):

change the values at lines **138-140** to

*rcolor: 255,*

*gcolor: 255,*

*bcolor: 0,*

and the blob will be red.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your comment but already we can do it red :D and also green, blue and yellow. We want to give what color we want. Example i want to give purple color but when we write its RGB code it doesnt work. So we dont understand how its working. Thats why we have to learn how its work